# PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted while using Selenium with Pythonista on iOS

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pythonista

I want to create a program in pythonista that can control the web browser. I know Selenium is the best for this but I have tried it on pythonista for my iOS iPhone and I get an error.

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
```

Here is the error:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/A2EBDF28-CB6C-4190-8199-7406AA3821A3/Pythonista3/Documents/selen.py", line 3, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/A2EBDF28-CB6C-4190-8199-7406AA3821A3/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/A2EBDF28-CB6C-4190-8199-7406AA3821A3/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/24DD2A57-320E-4E21-9BE2-7C3605830DE0/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 708, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/var/containers/Bundle/Application/24DD2A57-320E-4E21-9BE2-7C3605830DE0/Pythonista3.app/Frameworks/Py3Kit.framework/pylib/subprocess.py", line 1261, in _execute_child
    restore_signals, start_new_session, preexec_fn)
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

Comment: Update the question with code trials and error stack trace

Comment: Added code and error

Comment: I think you need to describe more

Answer (score 2):

This error message...

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

...implies that the **ChromeDriver** was unable to create a desired new **resource** e.g. *logfile* while initializing a new *WebDriver* and *Web Client* session.

As per the discussion  **`Pythonista`** - [**`Limitations due to iOS`**](https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/1975/limitations-due-to-ios) following are some of the limitations while using *Pythonista* :

- No fork/exec for new processes. Impacts the subprocess module.
- Due to missing fork, no full cleanup of process resources (memory, threads, file handles).
- No file access outside of application directory.
- No `/dev/null` and other special files.
- Limited processing power of devices (compared to typical PC/Mac).
- Process usually is stopped/killed after a while.

An simple example is as follows :

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C59C68D-71BF-4CBB-90F8-373A1752DEE1/Pythonista.app/pylib/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C59C68D-71BF-4CBB-90F8-373A1752DEE1/Pythonista.app/pylib/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/8C59C68D-71BF-4CBB-90F8-373A1752DEE1/Pythonista.app/pylib/subprocess.py", line 1205, in _execute_child
    self.pid = os.fork()
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

### What's wrong in your usecase

There can be 2 issues as follows :

- When you invoke the following line of code :

  ```
  browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```

  The *ChromeDriver* tries to *create*/*modify*/*access* the **scoped_directory** within the file system. For example on *Windows OS* :

  ```
  "chromedriverVersion": "2.35.528161 (5b82f2d2aae0ca24b877009200ced9065a772e73)",
  "userDataDir": "C:\\Users\\username\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\scoped_dir5188_12717"
  ```

  Possibly *ChromeDriver* is unable to perform this task/method/functionality.
- Again when you invoke the following line of code :

  ```
  browser = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```

  As per [**`selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver`**](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_chrome/selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.html#module-selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver) *ChromeDriver* tries to create a `logfile` within the file system as per the constructor as follows :

  ```
  class selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver(executable_path='chromedriver', port=0, options=None, service_args=None, desired_capabilities=None, service_log_path=None, chrome_options=None)
  ```

  Possibly *ChromeDriver* is unable to perform this task/method/functionality,

Due to the above mentioned reasons you are seeing the error :

```
PermissionError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted
```

### Solution

Incase of any of the above mentioned cases the solution would be to restrict the *access*/*creation* of the resources within the **application directory** only.